# Why is the $F_{\rm net}$ zero when we are on a surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Why is the $F_{\rm net}$ zero when we are standing still?

Comment: If $F_{\text{net}}$ was non-zero, the body would be accelerating according to the second Newton's law. But somehow it doesn't!

Comment: If an object is in equilibrium (i.e. it is not accelerating) then the net external force on it, $F_{net}$ must be zero - because if it wasn't the object *would be* accelerating. This is true no matter where the object is - it could be on the surface on the Earth, on the surface of another planet, in outer space etc. etc.

Comment: @gandalf61 Not necessarily true. The rotation of Earth means that any object at rest on the surface not at the poles is moving in a circle, so the net force is nonzero. An object on the surface of Earth isn't in equilibrium.

Comment: This $F_{net}$ be 0 is not just restricted to a surface. It's about the external factors.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning is usually the wrong way around. I would prefer to say "we are standing still, and *therefore* the net force is zero". In other words, you are standing still, so the floor somehow manages to balance your weight and the normal force it produces.

*How* the floor manages this is, is through a damping process. Usually, you would think of the floor as perfectly rigid. But any material is actually *slightly* deformable. You could think of the floor as a spring. Imagine you fall on this spring from 5 cm height or something small. As you touch the spring, the spring compresses and starts to create an upward force. The force of the spring keeps increasing because you are still moving downward. At some point the force of the spring matches your weight. You would think you would stop at this point, but so far the net force has still been downward and this means you still have velocity. As you spring compresses further, the net force is now upwards and you start slowing down. At some point your velocity is zero, but the force is still upwards. You get accelerated upwards and the process repeats but now in reverse. This time, some of your energy has been lost to deformation, sound and some heat.

Because you are losing energy each bounce, the amplitude of this oscillation will go down over time. When the amplitude is zero, the force of the spring is exactly matched by your weight.

How fast these oscillations die out depends on the damping strength. If the damping is strong enough, there will be only a single oscillation (which is the same as no oscillation at all).

Answer (score 0):

if you stand still your weight spread to your legs equally and they keep you in balance. So gravity force is downward and equals to your weight and your body applies the same force in opposite direction to keep you stand still. So in this case Fnet=0 because, if we sum the forces they neglect each other and Fnet=0
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers miss the important point: "still" implies that acceleration is zero. So it can immediately be concluded, from Newton's second law, that net force (and torque) are zero. The details of the forces are irrelevant. It is automatically true by definition of $F_{\text{net}} = ma$.

However, it is not true that the $F_{\text{net}}$ of someone standing still on Earth's surface is zero, unless they are at one of the poles. Due to the Earth's rotation, all points on the Earth's surface except the poles travel in circles, so there is a net centripetal force. This is why the normal force exerted by the ground is less than the weight. Therefore, regarding your original question, there isn't enough information to determine the weight from the normal force alone. The rotation rate of the planet, as well as the person's latitude, must also be specified.