# What exactly qualifies something to be a transverse wave?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

[image]

what exactly are transverse waves? other than the commonly repeated answer that propagation is perpendicular to direction of travel / oscillations

my answer to this was D, which was the most encompassing in my opinion, so why is it wrong?

Comment: If you took a guitar to the surface of the Moon, and you plucked its strings, you might argue that that was an example of transverse waves in a vacuum. But when people say that electromagnetic waves can "travel _through_ vacuum," what they really mean is, that electromagnetic waves do not require any physical medium. So, in that sense, answer D is the _least_ encompassing, not the most.

Comment: What you should do is not just jump to (D); instead say: (A) is wrong because [it's turtles all the way down]. (B) again, (C) one more time , (D) is correct because [your reason here], then we can get an idea of where you are. Moreover, the goal is not to be "most encompassing", it's to pick the statement that is "all encompassing"...so as multiple choice whizkid, I would search for a single counter example until one answer is left, and would not even think about why it is correct because it has to be correct...unless they drop an "(E): none of the above"...

Comment: @JEB What is wrong with response **C**?

Comment: @Farcher It comes to down to "all", which is ambiguous--is it all waves, all classes of waves, and if so: what's a wave class, are evanescent wave seperate--but any non-linear wave is out, a transverse soliton doesn't make standing waves.  May need a materials (dispersive elastic solids) or plasma expert to give the deets.  Obviously that's too advanced for the level of the question, but "all means all", and I'll chalk it up another example of poor educational material, confusing earnest students, displayed on this site. Let's have a title and author on these things.

Comment: @JEB If one follows your maxiim “all means all” to lots of other examples it would be impossible to teach “elementary” Physics. The exceptions you quote are not likely to be met until a more advanced Physics is undertaken when such a question would not be asked. It is not a particularly good question but in  the context of “elementary” Phyics there is a correct response.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual questions rather than a " do my homework for me" question.

Comment: I agree with @JEB. The above discussion is why this question is off-topic as it cannot be answered objectively.

Comment: @Farcher The problem with questions like this is that it is too localized. The assumptions or scope are too specific to the educational context (e.g. what is the definition of a "type" of transverse wave)? As such it's difficult, as someone without knowledge of the assumptions or context, to answer. This would be better suited for a dedicated homework help site. The same goes for [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/807356). The statement can be true or false depending on which assumptions you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement D is not true because there are transverse waves that require a medium to be vibrated and so do not travel in vacuum. Transverse waves on a rope is an example.

By a process of elimination I think C is the expected answer. You can form a "stationary" wave (I think this must mean a standing wave) from a transverse wave by fixing two nodes an appropriate distance apart - this is how guitar strings work, for example. However, this is not a defining characteristic of transverse waves, since it is also true of longitudinal waves e.g. in organ pipes.

Comment: yes it is C but i was confused about D, i think now that you bring up ropes i understand why its wrong... also ripples